# Using Python to find values from one excel sheet in another and printing result

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have 2 spreadsheets "Old_Data" and "New_Data", both contain a column called "ID" they can have 10K+ entries, and they are not ordered in anyway. I.E ID "1001" may be on row 2 in "Old_Data" but be on row 4500 in "New_Data"

There are also entries within "New_Data" that are not in "Old_Data" and vice versa. For now I'm trying to figure out how I can use Python to take every entry from "Old_Data" try and locate it within "New_Data" and then append a Field/Column called "Found" within "Old_Data" with a true or false based on if it was located or not.

Any ideas on how I would go about starting on this? I've attached a couple of examples of both "New_Data" and "Old_Data" excel sheets

[image: Old Data]

[image: New Data]

Answer (score 1):

You could read both columns to a list.

```
new_ids = list()
old_ids = list()
```

You have to fill those lists either converting your excel to a csv.file and read the lists from there using  input() / sys.stdin or alternatively using openpyxl or a similar module.

Afterwards, assuming all those IDs are unique elements:

```
old_d = dict(old_ids)

for id in old_ids: 
    pos = new_ids.index(id)
    old_d[id] = pos # position in the old list

    #or for simple existence:
    #old_d[id] = (id in new_ids) # just True / False

    #print(f'id {id} from new_ids is in old_ids at position {pos}')
```

In case of looking for the position: not found will be a -1 in your dictionary. 
Might be more useful to have a position then a simple existence check.

Its basically the same as Excels VLookup.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code and the corresponding result in old_data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
new_data = pd.read_excel('new_data.xlsx')
old_data = pd.read_excel('old_data.xlsx')
old_data['exists'] = np.nan
for each in list(old_data.loc[old_data.ID.isin(new_data['ID'])].index):
    old_data['exists'].iloc[each] = 'Exists'
old_data['exists'].fillna('non-existent', inplace=True)
print(old_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, it seems to work but I get the below error and it doesn't update the excel sheet. However when it prints, it seems to be finding matches etc;


```Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 671
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame```

Comment: its just a warning you can ignore :)  
and in order to update your sheet you have to write the contents into your sheet